# Drawing a Smooth Line from Tablet Input

Tags: drawing, spline

As the user drags their stylus across the tablet, you receive a series of coordinates.  You want to approximate the pen's path with a smooth line, trailing only a few sample points behind it.  How would you do this?

In other words, how would you render a nice smooth responsive line as a user draws it with their tablet?  Simply connecting the dots with straight lines is not good enough.  Real drawing programs do a much better job of curving the line, no matter how close or far the sample points are.  Some even let you give them a number to indicate the amount of smoothing to be done, accounting for jittery pens and hands.  Where can I learn to do this stuff?

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3347483/writing-a-paint-program-a-la-ms-paint-how-to-interpolate-between-mouse-move-eve

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know this is an old question but I had the same problem and I came with 2 different solutions:

- The first approach is use two resolutions: One , when the user is inserting the path points connecting them with straight lines. Two , when the user finish the stroke delete the lines and draw the spline over. That should be smoother than the straight lines.
- The second approach it is to smooth the new points with a weighted mean of the sampled points. So each time you get a new point [x1,y1] instead of painting it directly, you take the previous points [x2,y2] and create a new intermediate point with the weighted mean of the two points. The pseudocode could be something like:

  ```
  newPoint = [x1,y1];
   oldPoint = [x2,y2];

   point2Paint = [(x1*0.3) + (x2*0.7), (y1*0.3) + (y2*0.7)];
   oldPoint= newPoint;
  ```

Being 0.7 and 0.3 the coefficients for the weighted mean ( You can change them to get your desired smoothing :)

I hope this would help

UPDATE Dec 13:  Here it is an article explaining different drawing methods, there are good concepts that can be applied (edge smoothing, bezier curves, smooth joints)

http://perfectionkills.com/exploring-canvas-drawing-techniques

Comment: The perfection kills link is still great, 8 years and counting after initially being published. Thanks @kangax!

Answer (score 0):

I never had to implement these (only for academic purposes), but you may want to take a look at wikipedia's [interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation) article.

Extracted from the article:

> interpolation is a method of constructing new data points within the range of a discrete set of known data points.
>
> In engineering and science one often has a number of data points, as obtained by sampling or experimentation, and tries to construct a function which closely fits those data points. This is called curve fitting or regression analysis. Interpolation is a specific case of curve fitting, in which the function must go exactly through the data points.

Hope it helps.